# How to align Custom cells to Right Detail and Basic cells?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, layout, nslayoutconstraint

I am using static cells with 4 sections to create a Settings scene:

[image: Xcode screenshot]

For some cells I use the predefined styles: **Right Detail** and **Basic**.

But for the following cells I use **Custom** style with my own constraints:

- *Label* on the left and *Switch* on the right side (like the cell selected in above screenshot)
- *Slider* occupying the whole cell

**My problems:** I can not get the leading alignment right and also my 2-lines word-wrapping *Label* pushes a *Switch* to the right:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see at the top screenshot, my constraints for the problematic *Label* in **Custom** cell are:

- Align Center Y to Superview: 0 pixels
- Leading Space to Superview: 2 pixels (does not match **Right Detail** and **Basic**)
- Trailing Space to *Switch* equal or greater than: 4 pixels (still pushes the *Switch* too far to the right)

Please help, I wonder how other apps with Settings screens do it.

**SOLUTION:**

1. I have unchecked **Constrain to Margins** and set **Leading Space** to 15 pixels (thanks Andre)
2. I have solved my 2nd problem by lowering **Horizontal Content Compression Resistance Priority** of the *Label* to 250

Comment: Can you upload code ?

Comment: What is the trailing space for the Switch? Is the leading space for the Label _Relative to the margin_? _Relative to the margin_ works only in iOS 8, so the leading space will be different in iOS 7.

Comment: Sorry i mean project,

Comment: Use all custom cells so you have complete control over the constraints.

Comment: @rdelmar I understand, thank you. Do you know the cause for my 2nd problem - the Switch being pushed out to the right? It has a trailing space constraing, but for some reason it is not helping

Comment: Does the switch have a trailing space constraint to the cell's right edge? If so, it must have the wrong value, or you have conflicting constraints.

Answer (score 1):

If you use auto-layout,

you can turn on "Preserve Superview Margins" in

1. Content View
2. Your Label & Switch
3. Your custom Table View Cell

and leave Label's leading space and Switch's trailing space to 0 (default)