# UITableViewCell margin inconsistency (Static cells)

Tags: ios, autolayout, iphone-x

I have an interesting issue with a margin inconsistency between different devices. Here are 2 screenshots from iPhone X and iPhone 6+ respectively with the same iOS (11.4.1) and running the same app.

[image: margin inconsistency]

You can see that on the iPhone X everything is aligned properly (as well as in IB), but on the iPhone 6+ there's a 4 pixel inconsistency.

This is a table view with static cells. All the menu items are the Basic style, except the second one ("Offline mode") which is in Custom style with custom constraints. In basic style the UILabels have X=16. My custom constraint also has a constant value of 16.

Of course, I can change my custom constraint to 20, but then the situation flips. So on the iPhone 6+ it will be all aligned properly, but will be misaligned on the iPhone X.

I tried to find out where these 4 pixels are coming from, but found nothing. Please help.

Comment: have you tried looking into the view debug hierarchy? I'd first see the constraints set on the label, and then the tableViewCell and then the tableView itself. And then dig deeper if there's a difference between the two devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have pinned your label's leading edge to the *edge* of the content view with a constant of 16. That is not how the other cells work, so you get different results.

Instead, pin your label's leading edge to the *left margin* of the content view, with a constant of 0. The left margin is 16 on a smaller device and 20 on a larger device, which is exactly the difference you're seeing for the other cells (because that is exactly how they are configured).

Answer (score 1):

Matt's answer is correct. I just want to add more details, because it may be beneficial for someone else. So, it turns out that all I need to do is to check the following checkbox in my constraint properties in IB:

[image]

Looks pretty simple when you know where to look for.

Answer (score 0):

Generally as soon as you start needing to control the margins etc of table view cells your best bet is to leave the built-in stuff behind and make custom `UITableViewCell` subclasses with explicit constraints and subviews.

In this particular case the screen width is different and the basic cell type calculates its margin constraints relative to the screen width. If you look on the right side you will see the same kind of inconsistency with the positioning of your switch control relative to the disclosure indicator in other cells.

(EDIT: Easiest solution, depending on what you're aiming for, is as matt suggests, pin to the margin of the content view rather and the actual edge.)

If you want, you could adjust your own constraint on your custom cell so that it is not constant but relative. You could figure out what multiplier you would need by looking at a few [different device screen sizes](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions) to see if it's constant (e.g. iPhone 6, SE etc). But it may be more practical in the long run to use your own subclasses. Note you generally do want to use relative constraints for things like this, since your constant margins might look fine on one screen size but weird on another.

This is not ideal but technically you could also check what device the user is using (or what the view's width is) and return an appropriate constraint using a switch. Although, if you really are only concerned about the iPhone X vs the 6+, then you might want to consider doing that.

You might also want to consider using a form library like [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) but there's a bit of a learning curve with anything like that, especially when it comes to customizing the appearance of cells and their subviews.

Comment: Also not sure, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36233517/1032372) on another post may be relevant.